Azure App Service access directory on Azure Virtual Machine
I have an application running on Azure Virtual Machine. This application periodically generates a directory with output files
e.g.
/home/azureuser/appbase/strategy/results/2024-04-06_19-09-01
/home/azureuser/appbase/strategy/results/2024-04-06_20-20-01

Additionally, I have a streamlit application running as Azure App Service.
I wish to connect from my app service application (streamlit) to this directory /home/azureuser/appbase/strategy/results/ and browse through contents (it will basically load .csv files as dataframe and display as charts)
Any pointers on how to connect my app service application to virtual machine directory?
Note: I can make this setup work on my local machine (cause I have full access to all my directories)
Note2: The only work around i can think is to run my streamlit manually on my virtual machine. However, would prefer if it continues as app service.
